# Running applications on Linux which is created in Windows

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I create REST API in Visual Studio 2017 Community.

I'm adding support for Docker

I put on the repository that is associated with Docker

Docker automatically builds my image

In the code, I use the database `In memory`

When I want to run the image on the Docker, I get the information:

`LocalDB` name database

`Application startup exception
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this Platform.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.LocalDB.GetLocalDBConnectionString(String localDbInstance)`

From this it follows that the database in memory is not supported.

How to deal with this?

Comment: You should probably have a look at this first: https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb

Comment: You need to verify the compatibility of the used components with the dotnet core base docker image .. or use the windows image instead see this https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopModernizing/wiki/02.-How-to-containerize-the-.NET-Framework-web-apps-with-Windows-Containers-and-Docker

Comment: LocalDB is a special version of SQL Server for Windows local development only. If you intend to run the app on Docker, you should use a true database, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017